# plupload add file function

Tags: javascript, ajax, plupload

I have dragged'n'dropped a file on the textarea. I have the file object in JavaScript. So now I would like to call a function to add it to the `pluploadQueue`.

How do I do that?

I assumed that would be a function like:  `pluploadQueue.addFile( File )` or `uploader.addFile( File )` but I can't find it anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no included support yet to do that in plupload, but you can add it by exposing `addSelectedFiles`.

on plupload.html5.js search for where addSelectedfiles is defined and replace that line with:

```
var addSelectedFiles = uploader.addFiles = function(native_files) {
```

You can later access this from your instance by calling `myinstance.addFiles(...)`

You can see me making this suggestion around 7 months ago here: https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/461
sadly, the plupload devs are mostly MIA.

Comment: I read your suggestion on github. I have a similar usecase. I ended up recreating the addSelectedFiles function in my code, but it meant that I had to but the html5files variable in the global scope, so I could access it. Your solution is better I think.